# I want to add a relation in my charm for MySQL db and create some tables using my charm

Tags: mysql, juju

I have a charm XYZ. I want to add a relation between my charm & MySQL service and Create some tables in database, For doing that I am adding a hook for relation-join in my charm. I am not sure how to access mysql form my charm and create tables in MySQL database using my relation-join hook charm. 
My charm code is in Python.

Answer (score 1):

Your relation-join hook can get some useful information from the Mysql service - a username and password. You also have the server address, so your XYZ charm can use this info to make SQL calls to the database. You may want to check out a pyhton library for mysql.
http://zetcode.com/db/mysqlpython/

Comment: Yes I was able to access mysql.